# Ввод строк в цикле C++

Tags: c++, функции, циклы

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int SLEN = 30;
struct student
{
    char fullname[SLEN];
    char hobby[SLEN];
    int ooplevel;
};

int getinfo(student pa[], int n);
void display1(student st);
void display2(const student *ps);
void display3(const student [], int n);

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter class size: ";
    int class_size;
    cin >> class_size;
    while(cin.get() != '\n'){
        continue;
    }
    student *ptr_stu = new student[class_size];
    int entered = getinfo(ptr_stu, class_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < entered; i++)
    {
        display1(ptr_stu[i]);
        display2(&ptr_stu[i]);
    }
    display3(ptr_stu, entered);
    delete [] ptr_stu;
    cout << "Done\n";
    return 0;
}
int getinfo(student pa[], int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter your name: ";
        cin.getline(pa->fullname, 30);
        cout << "Enter your hobby: ";
        cin.getline(pa->hobby, 30);
        cout << "Enter your ooplevel: ";
        cin >> pa->ooplevel;
        cin.get();
        sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}
void display1(student st)
{
    cout << "Name: " << st.fullname << endl;
    cout << "Hobby: " << st.hobby << endl;
    cout << "Ooplevel: " << st.ooplevel << endl;
}
void display2(const student *ps)
{
    cout << "Name: " << ps->fullname << endl;
    cout << "Hobby: " << ps->hobby << endl;
    cout << "Ooplevel: " << ps->ooplevel << endl;
}
void display3(const student pa[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name: " << pa[i].fullname << endl;
        cout << "Hobby: " << pa[i].hobby << endl;
        cout << "Ooplevel: " << pa[i].ooplevel << endl;
    }
}
```

Здраствуйте я написал этот код для того чтобы она просила ввод через функцию и показала структуры через функции с другими способами показа(из книги упражнения) ну вот проблема в том что я пишу до определенной части и потом ввод сразу прекращается и я не могу полностью написать значения в массив структур и потом показывает содержимое а в содержимом непонятные строки по типу локация файла, вот и все я проверял код 5 раз все вроде бы норм, заранее спасибо за вашу помощь, и извините если есть какие тупые ошибки в коде(

Comment: Будет небесполезно воспользоваться отладчиком и выполнить в нем программу построчно, удостоверяясь, что каждая строка делает задуманное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас в функции ввода все значения вводятся в нулевой элемент `pa[0]`.  Т.е. `cin >> pa->ooplevel;` то же самое, что и `cin >> pa[0].ooplevel;`. Каждое следующее значение перезатирает ранее введенное.
Должно быть примерно так:

```
int getinfo(student pa[], int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter your name: ";
        cin.getline(pa[i].fullname, 30);
        cout << "Enter your hobby: ";
        cin.getline(pa[i].hobby, 30);
        cout << "Enter your ooplevel: ";
        cin >> pa[i].ooplevel;
        cin.get();
        sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

И зачем подсчитывается количество введенных записей? Количество объектов вводится в начале `main()`. В функции ввода обработки ошибок неправильного ввода значений нет - т.е. либо будет введено ранее известное кол-во записей, либо программа завершится с ошибкой.